# Improve htaccess rewrite for SSL, non WWW using subdirectories

Tags: .htaccess, https, url-rewriting, subdirectory

All the possible ways of writing a domain name should be rewritten to https and non-www. i.e.

```
example.com => https://example.com

www.example.com => https://example.com

http://example.com => https://example.com

http://www.example.com => https://example.com

https://www.example.com => https://example.com
```

Those rules also applies for all of the sub domains (https and non-www).

The main site should be rewritten to a folder called "main". At the moment I have one sub domain which should be rewritten to a folder called "sub".

So I got it working trough .htaccess but this code is a bit messy and I'm pretty sure there is a nicer/cleaner way to achieve what I want.

Could someone help me out to improve the following .htaccess?

```
RewriteEngine on 


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteCond http%1://%{HTTP_HOST} ^(https?://)(www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ %1%3%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/main/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sub/$1 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /sub/$1


# Force https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The URL of the main domain should be like: https://example.com and sub domain should be like https://sub.example.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use these rules

```
RewriteEngine on

#redirect main site to https non www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(mainsite\.com)$
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
#rewrite mainsite to /mainsite folder
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mainsite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mainsitefolder
RewriteRule ^ /mainsitefolder%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

#redirect subdomain to https and subfolder

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.domain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(sub\.domain\.com)
RewriteRule ^ https://sub.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
#rewrite subdomain to subfolder
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.domain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdomainfolder
RewriteRule ^ /subdomainfolder%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Your solution works perfect for the main domain, but fails for the sub domain. When I enter `https://www.sub.example.com` the www won't be removed and when I enter `www.sub.example.com` the www won't be removed and also this one is not redirected to https.